# fetching the page failed because it's denied by robots.txt

Tags: html, twitter, server, preview, twitter-card

I'm trying to validate my page with twitter tags in twitter card validator. But all times i get error: "ERROR: Fetching the page failed because it's denied by robots.txt."
 
If i try to watch on my robots.txt: 'http://domain.subdomain.com/robots.txt' it looks like:

```
User-Agent: Twitterbot
 Disallow:
```

I have tried to change it to:

```
User-Agent: *
 Disallow:
```

But it did not help.
Where im not right?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and after digging into it, I understood that the TwitterBot follows the internal redirects and they also should not be blocked.

I've used the following site [robots.txt Validator and Testing Tool](https://technicalseo.com/tools/robots-txt/) to see what's going on.
If you mark the Check Resources checkbox it will follow all redirects.

You can validate your Twitter card here: [Card Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator)